# Generate multiple Form Inputs php

Tags: php, forms, input

How do i get the values when submitted
I am generating the input via a loop based on the users selection but don't know how to retrieve the input values via post method

here is a sample of what i have

```
// string is based on database values it can be anything which i can't tell
Example code

$string = 'math,english,biology';

$exp = explode(',', $string);
foreach($exp as $value){
    print '<input type="text" name="'.$value.'[]" value=""  />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use name array (`name="blabla[]"`)

```php
$string = 'math,english,biology';

$exp = explode(',', $string);


if ($_POST) {
    foreach ($exp as $name) {
        if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
            echo 'input ' . $name . ' is ' . $_POST[$name] . '<br>';
        }
    }
    exit();
}


echo '<form method="post">';
foreach($exp as $value){
    print '<input type="text" name="'.$value.'" value=""  />';
}
echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button></form>';
```

Enter a, b, c to each input and submit. Here is the result:

> input math is a
> input english is b
> input biology is c

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in `value=""`, name the field and make it an array `[]`.

```
$string = 'math,english,biology';

$exp = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($exp as $value) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="fieldName[]" value="<?= htmlentities($value) ?>"  />
}
```

Then it will be accessible in *`$_POST['fieldName']` as an array.

**presuming you are using `method="POST"` on the form*

If `math,english,biology` are form keys, then do:

```
$string = 'math,english,biology';

$exp = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($exp as $key) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="fieldName[<?= htmlentities($key) ?>]" value=""/>
}
```

or

```
$string = 'math,english,biology';

$exp = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($exp as $key) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="<?= htmlentities($key) ?>" value=""/>
}
```

Comment: i want the fieldName to be the value from the loop result

Comment: Thanks for your time but how do i construct the post request when submitted since i the field names are dynamic

Comment: you wrap it in a form element, see the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Please take a moment and check my code please ...
since name="'. $value .'[]"  are dynamic so how do i get them when submitting via post

Comment: thanks for ur conribution